# Reading content of sundry text files in a WPF C# application

Tags: c#, wpf, list, collections, parameters

**EDIT:** I am trying to read the content of sundry (in this case: 7) text files in a WPF C# application. Therefor, I use the following code, which has been edited:

```
try
        {
            List<string> Verknüpfung = new List<string>();

            foreach (string Datei in Directory.GetFiles(V.PfadShortcuts, "*.txt"))
            {
                Verknüpfung.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(Datei, Encoding.UTF8));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= Verknüpfung.Count - 1; i += 2)
            {
                Image Icon = new Image();
                Icon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\Fugue Icons\document.png", UriKind.Relative));
                Icon.Height = 16;
                Icon.Width = 16;
                Icon.Stretch = Stretch.None;

                MenuItem MenuItem = new MenuItem();
                MenuItem.Click += delegate { Process.Start(Verknüpfung[1 + i]); };
                MenuItem.Header = Verknüpfung[0 + i];
                MenuItem.Icon = Icon;
                MenuItem.Padding = new Thickness(5);

                MI_Verknüpfungen.Items.Add(MenuItem);
            }
        }
```

I have 7 text files. Each contains the following: LINE 1: Title (like "Google"; for the HEADER) & LINE 2: Process (like "https://www.google.de/"; for the CLICK EVENT).

However, I get this result (Sorry for hiding information, but it contains business matters):
[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

So it seems to work. But unfortunately, when I click on one of them, I get the following error message:

German: "Der Index lag außerhalb des Bereichs. Er muss nicht negativ und kleiner als die Auflistung sein. Parametername: index"

English: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

It works, when I change the following:

Before: `MenuItem.Click += delegate { Process.Start(Verknüpfung[1 + i]); };`

After: `MenuItem.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(MenuItem_Click);`

```
public void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= Verknüpfung.Count - 1; i += 2)
        {
            Process.Start(Verknüpfung[1 + i]);
        }
    }
```

But now, when I click on one of the menu items, the application runs ALL processes (meaning all 7 "shortcuts" saved in my collection) - however, the error message disappeared. **How can I manage running only the process, that is clicked on?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed! ;)
The solution is to create a new var (tmp).

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Verknüpfung.Count - 1; i += 2)
            {
                Image Icon = new Image();
                Icon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\Fugue Icons\document.png", UriKind.Relative));
                Icon.Height = 16;
                Icon.Width = 16;
                Icon.Stretch = Stretch.None;

                var tmp = i;

                MenuItem MenuItem = new MenuItem();
                MenuItem.Click += delegate { Process.Start(Verknüpfung[1 + tmp]); };
                MenuItem.Header = Verknüpfung[0 + i];
                MenuItem.Icon = Icon;
                MenuItem.Padding = new Thickness(5);

                MI_Verknüpfungen.Items.Add(MenuItem);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well let's analyse your problem... you said:

> When I click on one of [the `MenuItem`s], I get the following error message:
>
> > "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

So you have a problem when you click on a `MenuItem`... let's see what you declared should happen when a `MenuItem` is clicked:

```
MenuItem.Click += delegate { Process.Start(Verknüpfung[0 + i]); };
```

Bingo! There's your `index` parameter and you're passing in the value `0 + i`. I'm curious though... why `0 + i`, when that is the same as just `i`? But anyway, so what does `i` equal?:

```
foreach (string Datei in Directory.GetFiles(V.PfadShortcuts, "*.txt"))
{
    ...
    i += 2;
}
```

What's that? `i += 2` But that means that for every file, you're trying to access a position in the `Verknüpfung` collection that is *twice* the number of files that you have. Now you didn't show how you declared that collection, but if it's an array of some kind, then I'd guess that the `i += 2` might work better if it were `i++` instead.

Of course if your files have just two lines in them, then that would explain that, but that's the best that I can guess from what you've shown. If that is incorrect, then just put a breakpoint in the `Click` handler and check the value of `i` and the number of items in the `Verknüpfung` collection and then you'll know what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. First let me comment: I say "0+i" because I want the application to go to the after next item in the next round of creating a menu item. So, I say i+=2 to GO TO THE AFTER NEXT ITEM in the next round of the loop. Collection declaration edited. Additionally I can say, that there are 14 items in the collection - I used Verknüpfung.Count to count them.